# Automatically scan USB drives for a folder and copy the contents to a specific directory

Tags: bash, usb, scripts, sync

I am having a bit of trouble with scripting.

I am setting up an HTPC for someone and I want things to be as plug and play as possible. I want to hand them a USB drive, have them plug it in and have it copy things on it's own without user input. I can do it with the same usb drive, but I want to future proof the setup so any USB drive with a specific directory works.

I know retropie and batocera use such a script, but when I try to adapt their script for the directories I need, it doesn't work.

here is their script
https://app.box.com/s/768hxe4vzpxqy7saanz3qyp9f3v5s6gh/file/418661902941

I try to point it to the right directories and drives but it always fails. Been toying with it for a couple days and I'm ready to tear my hair out.

I need it to find a directory named "media" on the root of the USB, and transfer the subdirectories and contents to the media directory on the root of the hard disk in the HTPC.

What am I missing?